# Perl/Tk widgets lists

Tags: arrays, perl, tk-toolkit

I wanna create user verification, where I've got two Tk::Entery widgets (one for user-name and one for password). Most of the properties for those are the same, so naturally I feel need of making some kind of OOP usage. I been trying several ways and non of them works.

Is there some way to bind two widgets in the samme list like so:

```
my @uv_entry = (my $uv_ent1 = $uv_frm1->Entry,
                my $uv_ent2 = $uv_frm1->Entry);
```

and use for them same `configure()` and `pack()` variant?

#### EDIT:

Well for my research, in the perldoc Tk::options, you can read fallowing synopsis (witch suggest one can use only one option with arrays?):

```
$widget->configure(-option=>value ?,-option=>value ...?);
@list = $widget->configure('-option');
@lol = $widget->configure;
```

Tk widgets are order in an hierarchy tree, starting from `MainWindow` and going down (like: `MainWindow` > `Frame` > `Entry` in this case). So I thought I need to put the `Frame` object as `$widget` value, so I did something like this:

```
my @uv_entry = (my $uv_ent1, my $uv_ent2);

@uv_entry = $uv_frm1->Entry->configure(qw/-width 16 -bg black
                -foreground green
                -disabledbackground grey
                -insertbackground green
                -insertwidth 5/
                )->pack(-side => 'top', -pady => 3);
```

What result with compiler telling me:

```
Can't call method "pack" on an undefined value at ./test.pl line 37.
```

That make me not happy, but directed with this I just try to compile without the pack subroutine. That compile fine, but left me with no result on the screen. (So far I know, Tk does not have any draw/render subroutine, it draw the widgets as far as they are initialized.)

Well now when I try to do anything, like printing some value from one element of `@uv_entry` list:

```
print $uv_entry[0]->cget('-bg') . "\n";
```

I get:

```
Can't call method "cget" on an undefined value at ./test.pl line 43.
```

Does `configure` subroutine not care about variable being correct type or defined at all? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] and add a bit more code, please? How have you used them?  I'm not familiar with TK, but I can explain what the code you've shown does. You will have the return value of `$uv_frm1->Entry` in `$uv_ent1`, and the return value of `$uv_frm1->Entry` in `$uv_ent2`. I guess `Entry` returns a fresh object at every call. Your `@uv_entry` will then be made up of `$uv_ent1` and `$uv_ent2`. So this code is valid and gives you an array with two things. But you don't use them for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `configure()` does not return the widget it was called on. That is why you cannot chain a call to `pack()` after calling `configure()`. But you can call `pack()` *before* you call `configure()` in a method call-chain (since `pack()` returns the widget it was invoked on).

So you could do this:

```
my @uv_entry = map { $uv_frm1->Entry() } 1..2;
$_->pack(-side => 'top', -pady => 3) 
  ->configure(
      qw/-width 16 -bg black
         -foreground green
         -disabledbackground grey
         -insertbackground green
         -insertwidth 5/
  ) for @uv_entry;
```